# IE doesn't use External CSS within a DIV

Tags: internet-explorer, stylesheet

If this question has been asked before - please forgive me, I couldn't find it.

I am AJAXing HTML documents to a div with javascript.  This code is a simplification.

Chrome-23 and FF-8 render the HTML using the ietest.css file but IE-9 does not.  Using
an iframe instead of a div would be difficult.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks,
John in Toronto

```
<!--
Style sheet contents:
p.bu1 {color: Blue; font-size:2em; font-weight:bold;}
p.rd1 {color: Red;  font-size:2em; font-weight:bold;}
-->

<html>
<head>
<script>
function write_doc()
{
  document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='ietest.css?v=1'>\
   <p class='bu1'>BLUE</p><p class='rd1'>RED</p>";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='div' onclick='write_doc()'>Click Me</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The link element can be used only within the head tag in IE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535848%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Teemu,

I found a work-around.

I load a CSS file (that covers most of the referenced styles) in the query page then preface a reference to one of its classes in the HTML string before sending it to the div.

e.g.

---

In the CSS file:
 ...
 span.ie_dummy {font-size: 0.1em;}
 ...

Script:

var archdoc = "<span class='ie_dummy'>&nbsp;</span>" + xmlhttp.responseText;

---

(&nbsp; must be used, a space character doesn't work.)

This requires me to amalgamate all the CSS files in the archive and get rid of any ambiguities.  I'm tempted to just leave IE users with unstyled text.  Maybe they'll switch browsers.